# msrtedit.dll cannot be loaded for vb6 project on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, vb6

I have loaded vb6sp6 on a Windows 8.1 new development PC.  Unfortunately when I attempt to open a project I receive the following error: 
'C:\Project Folder\MSRTEDIT.dll' could not be loaded--Continue Loading Project?

That dll is located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 but not the project folder, however copying it to the project folder still produces the error.  On my previous Windows 7 64-bit development PC the dll is just located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  If I click Yes to get past the error I receive the same error for MSCOMCTL.OCX  I can successfully register the ocx but it doesn't get rid of the error.

Any suggestions??

Comment: If doesn't belong in syswow64, how did it end up in there?  Are you copying files by hand and hope it will work?  It won't. It is an Office DLL, did you actually install the version of Office this program needs?

Comment: The dll does belong in SysWOW64, it was put there during the installation of the program, I did not copy it there by hand.  The program runs fine in Windows 8, but I am not able to modify the Visual Basic project on Windows 8.I did copy the dll by hand to the project folder to see if that would resolve my error - it did not.  I'm not sure if there is a problem with the Visual Basic installation or if something else is going on.  Everything works fine on Windows 7.

Comment: Hmya, an installer only ever makes an attempt at making the program runnable.  Making a mistake like this is pretty common.  It does squat to allow you to build the program.

Answer (score 0):

The installation puts msrtedit.dll in the system folder so that PCs without Access can still run the program. The problem on my Windows 8 machine is that the msrtedit.dll file installed in the SysWOW64 folder was older than the one used by Office 2013, so even though the .exe file was able to run, I couldn't modify the exe in VB6 because of the newer version of Office. I still have more configuring to do, but I at least know where the problem is now. Thanks for getting me moving in the right direction.